# Init grpc in flutter project

Tags: flutter, grpc

I create flutter project with grpc, but I get error, when try to generate file dart from proto. I put proto files in lib/protos (rewards.proto), then in terminal put command
'protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src -Iprotos protos/rewards.proto'

and I receiver error like this --dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: ═х єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы.

What I do wrong ? (Sorry for my English):)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this official installation docs : [grpc-dart](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/dart/quickstart/)

I hope you downloaded the protoc-plugin. You can do it using

$ dart pub global activate protoc_plugin

If you had already done this, add dart to path, You can do this

export PATH="/path/to/.pub-cache/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/path/to/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"

ps : The error you got is due to path related issues. The above two commands might help